# konvajs: item location not change after drag and drop

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

So with konva.js I have a group with two Text items. I made the group `draggable`.  After dragging it though I printed out `x` and `y` for the Text but it never changed:

```
group.on('dragend', function() {
    var group = this;
    var t = group.findOne('Text');
    console.log(t.x(), t.y());
});
```

The rest of the code is exactly the same as `Konva Text Demo`

Comment: Never used konva - but maybe the text position is relative to it's group? Could you expand your question a bit?

Comment: That helped a lot. Although I'm still having some issues but I'm ready to accept this if you promote this into a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Promoted from Comment:*

> Never used konva - but maybe the text position is relative to it's group? ...

In **konva.js** the `x` and `y` properties of a child element within a group is relative to it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

The code should look something like this:

```
if(imageObj.src.indexOf("icon_clock.png") > -1)
{
    clockX = (group.get('.topLeft')[0].getAbsoluteTransform().m[4]+group.get('.topRight')[0].getAbsoluteTransform().m[4])/2;
    clockY = (group.get('.topLeft')[0].getAbsoluteTransform().m[5]+group.get('.bottomLeft')[0].getAbsoluteTransform().m[5])/2; 
}

layerName.draw();
stageName.draw();
```

Comment: it's work good and also i can work on this. we can create a dynamically clock when clock move on stag that time arrow was also move in run screen.